# t-sql (SQL Server) solution to check file or directory exists using a user defined function

Tags: shell, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I read a lot of posts trying to find a solution for writing a function to determine if a file exists or at least the directory it sits in is valid. What I did research was solutions like using INSERT INTO temp table that is not permissible in a udf so I had to find another solution and I came up with a combination of a few using check file exists and command line shell script to check directory. Unless someone has a better idea?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_FileExists(@path varchar(512))
RETURNS INT --1 => File Exists, 2 => Directory Exists, 3 => Directory Does Not Exist
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result INT
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT
    IF @result <> 1
    BEGIN
        SET @path = 'IF EXIST "' + SUBSTRING(@path, 1, LEN(@path) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@path))) + '" (echo 1)'
        exec xp_cmdshell @path
        SET @result = CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT = 1 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END
    END
    RETURN @result
END
```

Comment: If you search for `[tsql] file exists` you'll find various solutions, e.g. the unsupported `xp_fileexist` SP.

Comment: Again it requires insert into table but declaring a table variable or temp table not permitted in a udf. Please post your working solution if u swear by it, I did try but with no luck

Comment: What I am also afraid of now that it comes to mind if I call this in a proc and the proc has declared NOCOUNT ON will it work, I will have to retest

Comment: Can you use CLR functions like [these](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=nclsqlclrfile)?